# Is there any generic DAO written for GraphAPI for OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB seems promising. Is there any well-written generic DAO for accessing the graph API? There are some snippets here and there in [this](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html) page but no concrete GenericDAO class implemented.Writing it is not a major problem. I was just checking if there is already something implemented.

Answer (score 1):

A [classical DAO pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) is used to abstract away the low level (database) details for the business layer. It is mainly used in the context of CRUD based applications using a RDBMS.

Because a Graph Database is a different beast, typically used in different contexts, i do no think a DAO pattern is a good fit for it. However, an abstraction layer **might** be a good decision depending on you use case. There are two good examples of such abstraction layers for Graph Databases:

- [Tinkerpop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/). OrientDB implements the Blueprints API directly (Warning: Tinkerpop 3 is not supported)
- [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/). An excellent implementation for Neo4j exists. However, the OrientDB support is not that good

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I thought I would introduce [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) as a solution which uses both [Tinkerpop](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org) and [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) to solve this issue.